# CSS font-size not being applied on mobile

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

**html**

```
<div class="footer">

    <div class="terms">
        <a href="terms.html" class="footer-text">Terms of Service</a>
    </div>

    <div class="contact">
        <a href="mailto:admin@thewhozoo.com?Subject=theWhoZoo%20query" target="_top" class="footer-text"><img class="email-icon" alt="Email" src="images/icon_email.png">admin@thewhozoo.com</a>
    </div>

</div>
```

**css**

```
.footer-text {
    font-size: 85%;
}
```

When I run this in a browser on my mac or pc, it works perfectly, i.e. the font is the correct size.  However, in Chrome on a phone, the font is at 100%, i.e. the 85% is not being applied.

[image]

If anyone can advise how I should rather structure my code, I would appreciate it.

Comment: How have you defined the global font size? Like do you have some sort of body{font-size 16px;}? Also, do you use pixels for your font size or em? I would suggest em, as it is scalable.

Comment: Hi Ruben, I don't define a global `font-size`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try something like this,

```
.footer-text {
    font-size: 1vw;
}
// you can try either,
.footer-text {
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

1vw = 1% of viewport width

1vh = 1% of viewport height

1vmin = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is smaller

1vmax = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is larger

Comment: I changed it to `font-size: 1em;`, which looks fine on a desktop browser, but is still too big on a mobile browser.  (see www.thewhozoo.com).

Comment: try vw . thats what i am use to do. it will scale your font size responsively

Answer (score 0):

For such situations, you can try bootstrap.
For much features, use bootstrap CSS and JQuery as well.

Try something like this:

```
 @media (min-width: 400px)
    {
        .footer-text 
        {
            font-size: 40px;
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 500px)
    {
        .footer-text 
        {
            font-size: 80px;
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 600px)
    {
        .footer-text 
        {
            font-size: 100px;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

there is problem about responsive with resolution put that line on your header file

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

after that make its responsive  with media query